# Find required dll's after linking to an external .lib file

Tags: windows, cmake, cpack

In one of my current projects, i am required to build a windows executable. We use external libraries (libpq). CMake finds the .lib files and is able to build against the library. However, we require to bundle the dependencies of libpq. We don't know them, as they can differ from the used libpq version.

Is there any way to scan for these dependencies (and their dependencies), so we can bundle them with the help of CPack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dumpbin.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-command-line?view=msvc-170), a command line tool which comes bundled with Visual Studio or the Windows SDK, ​with the `/imports` command line.  You can run it against on both your main EXE to discover which DLLs its dependent on as well on individual DLLs to see what they depend on.

Often times, I'll just run `dumpbin /imports foo.exe | findstr /i dll` to quickly find out what DLLs it depends on.

Another useful tool is [depends](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) (Dependency Walker). It's a bit dated, but it's a GUI version of dumpbin that shows you where the system finds dependent DLLs.

There's also [listdll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) from the Sysinternals group at MS.

> We don't know them, as they can differ from the used libpq version.

Yes you do. Whatever version of libpq you build with, you should ship the corresponding DLLs (if any) from that same version.

You typically hardcode your binary file dependencies instead of trying to do some build environment trickery. That is, you know you are linking with a DLL import library, you should know which DLLs you need to ship alongside your EXE.

If libpq is a completely standalone LIB that just statically links into your EXE, you are likely done. No further work to consider.

If libpq is a stub lib with a corresponding DLL, you ship the DLL (e.g. "libpq.dll") and its dependencies in the same folder as your EXE.

Again, dumpbin.exe will help you find the dependencies.  Also, read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order

Comment: We known we require libpq.dll, but libpq.dll depends on some other libraries like openssl, which can be libssl-1.0.1.dll or libssl-1.1.0.dll or ... you get it.

I can for sure hardcode these, but if upstream changes anything, the build will break. And we can not test against differen libpq versions

Comment: @ThomasBerger - I'm not sure I quite understand. Why wouldn't you ship the same libpq DLLs (and dependent DLLs)  as your daily build links with?  I'm not sure how your upstream branches work, but wouldn't you block the merge or pull request if it was going to break the build?  Consider the cost of fixing the broken build once in a blue moon compared to the cost of a sophisticated script that tries to auto infer DLL dependencies. I'm happy to be educated on this topic if there's something I'm missing.

Comment: becuase this library is delivered as an open source project. Providing builds is one thing. Having everybody to figure it out wich libraries are required for the specific installed version is another thing.

And most libraries libpq ships with are not required as these are for other tools or the PostgreSQL Server itself

Comment: Oh I see, you are shipping an open source project that depends on libpq.lib being supplied by the person or team building your EXE.  Is that correct?

Comment: libpq.lib is part of the windows version of PostgreSQL, supplied by EDB. libpq is the official client library for PostgreSQL. But I (a linux dev, not a windows guy) thought this would be a common issue for windows Software. We are currently fiddling with `dumpbin`. Maybe i can create a stand alone CMake Module for this case. Thx